# Stop Podio calculation after certain event

Tags: podio

We currently have a counter that calculates from "Enrollment date" to "today" by weeks.

We'd like the weeks to stop being counted once a separate field ("Offer sent") is updated.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways of handling this. Here is one of examples. So, Podio app has 2 fields, `Date` with date and time set, and `Category` with multiple options to show how you can handle date and time.

```
var category = @Category;
var now = new Date;
var today = new Date;
today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
var durationTillNow = (now - @Date)/1000/60/60/24;
var fromDate = @Date;
fromDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
var durationTillNowWithoutTime = (today - fromDate)/1000/60/60/24;

if (category == 'round to nearest number') {
  "Rounded to: " + Math.round(durationTillNow).toString() + " day(s)";
} else if (category == 'round up') {
  "Round up: " + Math.ceil(durationTillNow).toString() + " day(s)";
} else if (category == 'round down') {
  "Round down: " + Math.floor(durationTillNow).toString() + " day(s)";
} else if (category == 'show full diff') {
  "Full diff: " + durationTillNow.toString() + " day(s)";
} else if (category == 'just ignore time') {
  "Ignoring time part: " + durationTillNowWithoutTime.toString() + " day(s)";

} else if (category == 'something else') {
 "it's something else selected";
} else {
  "yet another else option selected";
}
```